# How to unfloat a table or figure environment

Tags: floats

Someone knows how to "unfloat" a table or figure environments. I mean, I want to put a float environment after a specified paragraph. I need some help.

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: why make it float at all in that case? Just use `tabular` or `\includegraphics` and it never moves, the only reason to put it in a figure is to allow it to float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think some people may think a float environment is required in order to have a caption...